# How can I execute one code block from local/master/control node?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I would like to execute the below tasks which create a user on a remote host and trigger an SMS gateway call from master/control node.

This is running from awx/(tower) where I get some of the parameters through an AWX survey.

```yaml
  - name: create users
    user:
            name={{ user_name }}
            comment={{ user_comment }}
            shell=/bin/bash
            home=/home/{{ user_name }}
            state=present
            createhome=yes
            password={{ my_pass | password_hash('sha512') }}
            update_password=on_create
    register: user_created

  - name: Expire password
    shell: chage -d 0 {{ user_name }}
    when: user_created.changed

  - name: Sent SMS to user
    uri:
            url: "http://example.com/bms/soap/Messenger.asmx/HTTP_SendSms?\
                  customerID={{ customerID }}&\
                  userName={{ userName }}&\
                  userPassword={{ userPassword }}&\
                  originator={{ originator }}&\
                  smsText=Hostname:%20{{ ansible_hostname }}%0aIP%20Address:%20{{ ansible_ssh_host }}%0ausername:%20{{ user_name }}%0aPassword:%20{{ my_pass }}%0a%0aNOTE:User%20needs%20to%20change%20password%20upon%20first%20login&\
                  recipientPhone={{ phone_number }}&\
                  messageType=Latin&\
                  blink=false&\
                  flash=false&\
                  Private=false&\
                  defDate=20220518090503"
    when: user_created.changed
```

Comment: Are you sure Ansible is the appropriate tool for this use case?

Comment: Since AWX is installed and we are using this for user creation, i thought of using it in this way

Comment: See [controlling where tasks run](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)

Comment: i tried deligate_to with multiple block, still no luck



* Unsupported parameters for (uri) module: delegate_to - added into uri block

* tried addinb url into block and gave deligate_to, still it ran on remote server.

Comment: Can anyone help on this ?